# When I merge by distance the model gets these distorted shadows

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, edges, weight-painting, shadows

I'm new to this so not sure if I'm explaining it all correctly, but basically in order to parent with automatic weights, I have to use "merge by distance", otherwise it doesn't work. Now when I do this the model starts to look a little weird and honestly I have no clue why in the first place all the vertices are detached from each other cause I don't remember doing that. But does anyone know how to merge by distance while keeping the model looking the same or at least similar?
[image]
[image]

Here's a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PcmUFIxb2ng5YvfKcGmG7qqcuI5KJjy9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello could you please highlight the distortion you are talking about? Does it have to do with your image textures? You haven't packed them

Comment: Can you try Right-clicking and selecting Shade Autosmooth then turning the Angle up to 180 degrees on the bottom-left Shade Smooth dialog that appears. I suspect your overlapping verts are due to the strange topology you have round the edges of the coat of your model.

Comment: @JohnEason That completely fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! Glad to help!